# ColdFusion REST Services not allowing a struct to be sent back in "content" when status code is 4xx

Tags: json, api, rest, coldfusion

I am using CF REST Services and we would like to send back a detailed error struct when a requestor submits data that does not pass our internal validation check. I am using setRestResponse to manipulate the status code (which works fine on all accounts). However when someone fails validation I would like to send a struct back to the user with a 400 or a 401. My research lead me to putting the struct in the "content" part of my return struct to setRestResponse however when I do that, I get the correct statuscode but not the JSON struct of the error detail.

One thing Im observing is my api seems to be returning HTML, even though I have set the "produces" attribute of my function to "application/json". I have also set the function to void since we are using setRestResponse. Can you help me figure out how to send back an error detail struct with a 400 error? What exactly needs to happen to make the API respond with JSON beyond what Ive done already?

Ive included a snippet of my code below:

```
        <cfif IsDefined('val_check_fail')>
            <!---The val_check returned an error.  Stop processing and return a REST error--->
               <cfscript>
                   error_struct = StructNew();

                   error_struct.errorText = val_check;
                   error_struct.errorCode = 3254;
                   out_struct = serializeJSON(error_struct);
               </cfscript>
            
               <cfset response.status = 400/>
               <cfset response.content =  #out_struct#/>
               <Cfset pyld = response/>
              
        <cfelse> 
            <cfscript>
                ins_payload = invoke(val_obj, 'insert_payload', {value_string:#insert_value_list#,col_string:#insert_list#});
            </cfscript>

            <cfscript>
                success_struct = StructNew();
                success_struct.message =  "Validated and Accepted For: " & #arguments.messageID#;
                
                out_struct = serializeJSON(success_struct);
            </cfscript>

            <cfset response.status =200>
            <cfset response.content = #out_struct#> 
            <cfset pyld = response/>
        </cfif>
        
       
        <cfscript>
            restSetResponse( pyld );
        </cfscript>
```

Comment: You need to include the definition of `restSetResponse()` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us any example of an actual output that you're seeing?

One thing I noticed in your code...since you have set the CF "produces" attribute of your function to "application/json" then you do not have to worry about any serialization of your data in the function.  CF will do that for you.  However, you are serializing your output like so:

out_struct = serializeJSON(error_struct);

It looks like this may be unnecessary, but I'd need a better look at what you're doing and what you're trying to do.